# How to tabulate list of lists in custom tabular way?

Tags: python

I'm trying to tabulate the following input list that have a stacked structure of parameters (first column) and values(second column) in multiple blocks as shown below. To the left I show the tabulated output. I show the list in colors to see more clearly how is the way to tabulate it. Many thanks for help in advance.

[image]

**input characteristics:**

- First block of data (first row to be tabulated), begins with "WORLD" and begins with "CAPITAL".
- Then could continue 0 o more blocks containing only a few parameters, that begins with "COUNTRYCODE" and ends with "CAPITAL".
- Then could be others blocks that begins with "CONTINENT" and ends with "PRM"
- Then could be others blocks that contains only "PRM".

**The conditions to tabulate are:**

- Headers would be the unique parameters from input list.
- Don't need to print "POLCODE"
- Below each parameter (header), goes each corresponding value.
- Each block that begins with "WORLD" would be a new row in output.
- Each block that begins with "COUNTRYCODE" would be a new row in output.
- How to know if "COUNTRYCODE" belongs or not to a bigger block that begins with "WORLD"? Well, one row only could have the value of each parameter. If one parameter appears again, should go in another row. The same applies to "PRM".
- For "PRM" values extract the numbers after "ncc" and after "kng".
- Finally do a fill down for values from "WORLD" up to "GOVERMENT" and a empty "SUMMARY" column for some further processing.

This is the code I have so far that is not giving me the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

input = [
        ['WORLD', '1'], ['CONTINENT', '1'], ['CONTINENTNAME', 'AMERICA'], ['CONTINENTCODE', 'AME01'], 
        ['GOVERNMENT', 'PRE'], ['COUNTRYCODE', '55'], ['COUNTRY', 'BRAZIL'], ['CAPITAL', 'BRASILIA'], 
        ['COUNTRYCODE', '51'], ['COUNTRY', 'PERU'], ['CAPITAL', 'LIMA'], ['COUNTRYCODE', '1784'], 
        ['COUNTRY', 'SAINT_VINCENT'], ['CAPITAL', 'KINGSTOWN'], ['WORLD', '1'], ['CONTINENT', '3'], 
        ['CONTINENTNAME', 'EUROPE'], ['CONTINENTCODE', 'EUR03'], ['GOVERNMENT', 'KNGD'], 
        ['COUNTRYCODE', '359'], ['COUNTRY', 'BULGARIA'], ['CAPITAL', 'SOFIA'], ['COUNTRYCODE', '36'], 
        ['COUNTRY', 'HUNGARY'], ['CAPITAL', 'BUDAPEST'], ['CONTINENT', '2'], ['CONTINENTNAME', 'ASIA'], 
        ['CONTINENTCODE', 'EXC35'], ['GOVERNMENT', 'KNGD'], ['POLCODE', 'ASIRPL2'], 
        ['PRM', 'kng.cc060.ncc458.svfdata'], ['PRM', 'kng.cc392.ncc392.svfdata'], ['CONTINENT', '5'], 
        ['CONTINENTNAME', 'AFRICA'], ['CONTINENTCODE', 'EXC35'], ['GOVERNMENT', 'PRE'], ['POLCODE', 'AFRRPL5'], 
        ['PRM', 'pre.cc231.ncc251.svfdata'], ['PRM', 'pre.cc324.ncc224.svfdata'], ['PRM', 'pre.cc450.ncc261.svfdata'], 
        ['PRM', 'pre.cc686.ncc221.svfdata'], ['PRM', 'pre.cc788.ncc216.svfdata'], ['PRM', 'pre.cc148.ncc235.svfdata']
        ]

headers = ["WORLD", "CONTINENT","CONTINENTNAME","CONTINENTCODE","GOVERNMENT","COUNTRYCODE","COUNTRY","CAPITAL","PRM"]
headers_count = [0]*9

out = []
current_row = [""]*9

for f,s in input:
    idx = headers.index(f)
    headers_count[idx] +=1
    if headers_count[idx] < 2:  ## If parameter appears more than once then print it in other row.
        current_row[idx] =s
    else:
        out.append(current_row)
        current_row = [""]*9
        current_row[idx] = s
        headers_count = [0]*9
        headers_count[:2] = [1]*2

# Insert headers as the first row
out.insert(0, headers)

# Create a DataFrame from the output list
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
```